# Python-pptxで日本語フォントを書式設定できない

Tags: python, wsl, font

[Python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) で既存のテキストフレームに対して日本語テキストを挿入し、そのフォントとサイズを変更したいです。
しかし、挿入するテキストが英語の場合フォントが反映されますが、挿入するテキストが日本語の場合フォントの反映がされません。解決法を教えてください。

また、下記のコードはWSL上で実行していますが、以下の記事を参考にWSL上でWindowsのフォントを指定できるようにしています。

[WSLでWindows10のフォントを使用する](https://qiita.com/query1000/items/6ea7665529b022eb5f45)

以下該当コードです。
※該当処理部分のみを記載しています。

```
～～～ファイル読み込み等省略～～～
for sp in slide.shapes:
    if not sp.has_text_frame:
        continue
    # 編集したいテキストフレームを絞り込み
    if str(sp.shape_type) == 'TEXT_BOT(17)':
        textFrame = sp.text_frame
        if str(textFrame.text) != '':
            pg = sp.text_frame.paragraphs[0]
            rn = pg.runs[0]
            rn.font.name = 'Meiryo UI'
            rn.font.size = Pt(10)
～～～ファイル保存等省略～～～
```

Comment: [Font typeface](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/txt-font-typeface.html) の`Related MS API`には`Font.NameFarEast`が記載されていますが、それを細かく区別出来るようにはなっていないのかもしれませんね。こちら [XML specimens](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/txt-font-typeface.html#xml-specimens) に例示されているXMLの説明を見ると`Asian characters, or possibly Asian font being applied:`とは書いてありますが、その中身の箇所が`lang="en-US"`になっているのに違和感があります。もしかしたらXMLの中を`lang="ja-JP"`に変えると何か変化が起きたりするかもしれませんね。

Comment: あるいは「日本語の場合フォントの反映がされません。」と言う時の確認環境は何処でしょう？ 確認しているのがWSL/Windowsのどちら(両方?)かも記述しておいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: @kunif  XMLを変更するのは可能性がありそうですね。後ほど試させていただきます。確認環境ですが、WSL上になります。Windows環境では試せていません。
こちらの機能はWSLで動作させたい願いがあるので、可能であればWSL上で動作することを前提としたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

手元の環境で`a:ea`タグの`typeface`属性を直接書き込むことでフォント名を反映できました。
下記はWindows11、Python 3.11.0、python-pptx 0.6.22上で動作を確認したサンプルコードです。
WSLでは動作確認していません。

**サンプルコード**

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Pt
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE_TYPE
from pptx.oxml.ns import qn
from lxml import etree

prs = Presentation("hoge.pptx")
slide = prs.slides[0]
for sp in slide.shapes:
    if not sp.has_text_frame:
        continue
    # 編集したいテキストフレームを絞り込み
    # if str(sp.shape_type) == 'TEXT_BOT(17)': # 'TEXT_BOX (17)'の間違い？
    if sp.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.TEXT_BOX:
        textFrame = sp.text_frame
        if str(textFrame.text) != '':
            pg = sp.text_frame.paragraphs[0]
            rn = pg.runs[0]
            rn.font.size = Pt(10)
            #`a:ea`タグの`typeface`属性を直接書き込む
            rpr = rn._r.get_or_add_rPr()
            ea = etree.SubElement(rpr, qn('a:ea'))
            ea.set('typeface',"Meiryo UI")
            #ea.set('typeface',"UD デジタル 教科書体 N-B") # 日本語フォント名もOK
prs.save('fuga.pptx')
```

**参考資料**

- [Adding highlighting to a run in python-pptx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61922353)
- [Change font name not working for asian characters. #768](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/768)

  - からの中国語リンク [已解决：Python-pptx中文字体](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/548039429)
- [XML specimens](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/txt-font-typeface.html#xml-specimens)
  コメントにあるリンク

**補足**

`a:ea`タグがない状態で`rn.font.name`や`rn.font.NameFarEast`を追記しても左記のタグは追加されませんでした。
QAサイトではタグを直接書き換える方法を多く見かけるので、`python-pptx`はまだアジアのフォントに対応できていないのかもしれません。

Comment: ea.setの後にrn.font.nameを指定をする必要がありましたが、こちらの方法で解決しました。ありがとうございました。